# How to make ScrollView consume touch event even when it's scrolled to the end?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, touch, stackview

I have an `FSPagerView`, which has an item that contains scrollable barchart (scrollview having multiple stackviews). When I scroll barchart, if there is a scrollable space, then touch event is consumed by the barchart and it scrolls. If there is no scrollable space on a side and I keep scrolling to that side touching barchart, it does not consume touch event anymore and instead the whole `FSPagerView` scrolls. How can I make scrollview consume touch event even in such case? In short, I don't want to scroll `FSPagerView` when touching barchart.

Here is a video:
https://streamable.com/kuxta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prioritize the `UIGestureRecognizer` of the two scroll views using the [require(toFail:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require) method.

Here is the code I tried:

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: collectionView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

I don't know if it's exactly what you were looking for. As soon as the `collectionView.panGestureRecognizer` detects something, the scroll view won't scroll.

Comment: I get NSInvalidArgumentException "UIScrollView's built-in pan gesture recognizer must have its scroll view as its delegate"

Comment: I tried subclassing scrollview, overriding this method, it gets called, but then I can't swipe barchart at all. When I swipe it, pager view swipes. I tried reverting the condition with negation, but then the initial problem becomes present again

Comment: would you provide a working example? I tried subclassing with no luck

Comment: I tried your code, it made the scroll of barchart impossible. When I try to scroll barchart, pagerview is always scrolled. Then I reversed it so that collection view's recognizer fails scrollview's recognizer and it looks fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manipulate UIScrollView's gesture recognizer:

scrollView.panGestureRecognizer

I never tested it with UIScrollView's panGestureRecognizer, but general idea is to 
add a gesture recognizer to FSPagerView and to set relations (using UIGestureRecognizer's delegate) between that recognizer and panGestureRecognizer to prevent it from firing

Comment: can you provide a more detailed code example? Otherwise the answer is useless

Comment: Ok, I will add an example, probably tomorrow. Honestly, I don't remember exact method names, so it requires some experimentation, but I have no spare time to do so :(

Answer (score 1):

`FSPagerView` exposes `panGestureRecognizer` that is essentially the underlying `UICollectionView`'s `panGestureRecognizer`.

I think you can just disable it while you are seeing the barchart.

Not very familiar with `FSPagerView`, but I think you can detect in which page you are by monitoring `FSPagerViewDelegate` callbacks. For example, if the bar chart is in the first page (i.e., index == 0), probably you can do something like this.

```
override func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, willDisplay cell: FSPagerViewCell, forItemAt index: Int) {
    // FSPagerView's gesture recognizer is only enabled for index > 0.
    pagerView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = (index != 0)
}
```

If that callback does not work, I would try the same thing with `func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, didSelectItemAt index: Int)` callback.